# Dynamically create and use schemas in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, database-design, entity-framework-core

I am creating an ASP.NET Core Web API for companies and I need each company to have its own database schema containing all the database tables.
This means that I dynamically have to create a new database schema each time a new company entity is created, and use a specific schema when a company is logged in.
How can the creation and usage of dynamically created schemas be achieved using .Net Core Web API and EF Core?

Currently the database context dependency injection is set up in the `Startup.cs` using the connection string dbConnection defined in 
`appsettings.Development.json`, like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...

services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(opt => 
  opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("dbConnection"));

...
}
```